# How does Google/Facebook chat know which users are currently logged on?

Tags: chat

This is a admittedly a bit of a terrible question, but my search results are clogged up by loads of privacy concerns: At a high level, can someone explain to me how I can detect which users are currently logged on to my website? (I happen to be building a Facebook clone for a school project if that helps to frame the question.)

Comment: if rekire and olivehour's answers are downgraded, I expect you to downgrade my answer as well. You might want to comment on why that doesn't answer your question, or adapt your question, because imo that's exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I don't know how facebook does it, but I saw this question earlier today and spotted the "[Presence](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/a0aev1q0skq)" tutorial application from Firebase. It queries a persistant store (database row) to see if a user is "logged in". Whether you use a database or session cookies, you'll just need to access login and logout events to determine if a user is online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what happens when users log on to your site? A session is created on the server side, linking the users' future requests to the login. This has to happen because HTTP itself is stateless -- that is, it wouldn't know that the person now requesting their profile page is the same that just authenticated, unless you have the client send back some piece of information, typically a cookie or, less frequently nowadays, a session ID in the URL.

That means that somewhere on your server, you already have the information on how many people are logged in (i.e. have a current session). If you're using a web framework, you may have to look into the details of its session management. If you aren't, you've already solved the problem; just find out where sessions are stored and voila, you know which users are online.

Of course, you don't know if the user went away without logging out, but that's a problem that's not easily solved; session management systems typically expire the session after a given period of inactivity (i.e. your server hasn't recieved any requests recently), so you could just go with whatever that system tells you to begin with. If you want something more, you can keep track of the last activity yourself and decide a user is inactive if that activity lies more than `n` minutes in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer is going to depend on which frameworks you are using to create your site, but in general terms, it is possible for browsers to keep an open connection with a web server, which enables bi-directional communication. This is sometimes known as COMET.

Facebook etc, then can track what open connections it has, and which user is logged in, and originating the connection (using the same session technology it uses to maintain user state across requests).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Javascript heartbeat to your web pages that checks in every minute, and if you haven't heard from them in a couple of minutes then assume they're logged out. Otherwise, if your site is session based, assume they're logged out when their session expires.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually ever studied it, but I'd assume that a HTTP request which hangs indefinitely would be closed the moment someone closes the page. You can use this to your advantage, by using a request like this to poll for when the user closes the page.

Alternative: poll with AJAX every 10 seconds for new messages and simply say that a user is gone when there has been no polling for 15 seconds.

However, detecting **in realtime** when the user quits the page has always been a large problem.

Answer (score -1):

When a user signs into your site, you log their activity to a database. Then, you go about detecting their activity on the site. If they have been idle for a certain amount of time (for example their last activity was 10 or 15 minutes ago), you can assume they are offline.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is by IP.

Each request to your website will be requested by an IP address. You main (index) file must have a logic to store this information somewhere or display it to you.

That's the simplest way to find out the people currently viewing your website.